# Oracle SQL: Extracting text between two characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring

I have strings that look like

```
{ABCDE}{F1}
{GHIJ}{K12}
```

I want to extract the text between the first curly brackets

```
ABCDE
GHIJ
```

I tried searching online but a lot of answers seem to be using functions or PL-SQL. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: read up about regular expressions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('{ABCDE}{F1}', '\{([^}]+)\}', 1,1,NULL,1) AS output
FROM dual
```

### Demo

This is a less commonly seen use of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, which uses a capture group, per this pattern:

```
\{([^}]+)\}
```

The sixth parameter says to return the first capture group.

Comment: I think the last `\}` in the regex is not necessary

Comment: @DavidFaber Yes it is, because perhaps there are values in that column which don't have a closing bracket, in which case we might not want to capture them.  It depends on what we assume about the OP's data.  I tend to play it safe.

Comment: Great answer, but do you mean the sixth parameter not the fourth?  I took your code and got this to work for the second string in the example : regexp_substr(raw_text, '\{([^}]+)\}', 1,2,NULL,1)

Comment: @ChristianPalmer Maybe reload your page to see what the OP's actual data looks like.  The fourth parameter, which you have changed in your query from 1 to 2, just says to take the second match, instead of the first.  This isn't what the OP wants, if I read correctly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - you are correct - I am just too slow to keep pace with the World :)

Answer (score 7):

This is old skool.  I love regular expressions and can understand them but get into an awful lot of trouble when I try to produce them.  A bit like Spanish (for me).  So this is just SQL INSTR / SUBSTR / REPLACE.  I'm not expecting any upvotes...

```
WITH test_data (raw_text)
 AS 
  (SELECT '{ABCDE}{F1}' from dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '{GHIJ}{K12}' from dual 
  )
SELECT
 raw_text
,SUBSTR(raw_text,2,INSTR(raw_text,'}{')-2)              first_string
,REPLACE(SUBSTR(raw_text,INSTR(raw_text,'}{')+2),'}')   second_string
--these two from Tim's excellent answer
,regexp_substr(raw_text, '\{([^}]+)\}', 1,1,NULL,1) 
,regexp_substr(raw_text, '\{([^}]+)\}', 1,2,NULL,1)
FROM
 test_data
;
```

### Demo

Comment: Actually, using the base string functions usually outperforms regex, at least for simple manipulations like this one.  But, it has the downside that the code can be harder to read and perhaps maintain +1.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like the following:

```
SELECT TRIM( '{' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(mystring, '\{[^}]+') )
  FROM mytable;
```

This will capture the text from the first opening curly brace up to but not including the closing curly brace, then trim the opening curly brace from the result.

Hope this helps.