# Oracle SQL, getting string value between 2 points

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, substr, instr

I need to select a string value between two dots. (dots include)

Given `abc.musadeneme.dce` I need `.musadeneme.`

I need your help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL: Extracting text between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004535/oracle-sql-extracting-text-between-two-characters)

Comment: does the source data always include both dots?  What if one is missing.  What if there are 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` (which is much faster than regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         value,
         INSTR(value, '.', 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, '.', 1, 2) + 1 - INSTR(value, '.', 1, 1)
       ) AS match
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'abc.musadeneme.dce' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MATCH |
| --- |
| .musadeneme. |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DZ6EQIPz)

Comment: Thank a lot. This usage is so fit to me.

Answer (score 2):

Given your exact specs, this solution using REGEXP_SUBSTR will do it. Match a literal dot, followed by all characters up to and including the next literal dot.  Note the 'WITH' clause just defines the set of test data, like a temp table in this case.

```
WITH tbl(str) AS (
  SELECT 'abc.musadeneme.dce' FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '(\..*?\.)') AS middle_string
from tbl;


MIDDLE_STRING
-------------
.musadeneme. 
1 row selected.
```

If no match is found, REGXP_SUBSTR returns NULL.  If there are more dots, this only returns the first substring surrounded by dots since the question mark makes the match non-greedy (stop at the first encountered match).

Answer (score 0):

Using `instr` and `substr` functions we can achieve this.

```sql
SELECT
    'ab.welcome.bye'                                                               AS inp,
    substr('ab.welcome.bye',
           instr('ab.welcome.bye', '.', 1) + 1,
           (instr('ab.welcome.bye',
                  '.',
                  instr('ab.welcome.bye', '.', 1) + 1)) - instr('ab.welcome.bye', '.', 1) - 1) AS outp
FROM
    dual;
```